# Add new value to Collection. Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to add a value to a couple Eloquent searches and would like to add to the search results an extra value, the value would be a boolean and would be used to check if the user has completed a survey in order to display it. 
These are my searches

```
//surveys sent to a group
$evaluatorGroup = EvaluationEvaluator::with('group.users', 'evaluation.survey')
    ->whereHas('evaluation', function ($query) use ($now) {
        $query->whereDate('init_date', '<=', $now);
        $query->whereDate('end_date', '>=', $now);
    })
    ->whereHas('group.users', function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
    })
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    ->get();

//surveys sent to the induvidual user
$evaluatorUser = EvaluationEvaluator::with('evaluation.survey')
    ->whereHas('evaluation', function ($query) use ($now) {
        $query->whereDate('init_date', '<=', $now);
        $query->whereDate('end_date', '>=', $now);
    })
    ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->get();
```

```
//the info for people who have answered is saved in the table survey_answers
Schema::create('survey_answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('survey_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('survey_question_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->text('answer');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('survey_id')->references('id')->on('surveys');
    $table->foreign('survey_question_id')->references('id')->on('survey_questions');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});

//in the survey_answers model I have the survey_answers relationship
survey->answers
```

Ideally I would just like to add a value called `answered` as a Boolean so that I can check that and either display the survey or not. The end result I want is to hide the surveys on the dashboard the the user has already answered so that they don't always appear even though they have been answered.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You have Eloquent relationships with many records. To which specific Eloquent collections do you want to add the new property?

Comment: @user8555937 for each item in the collections in the code above, so if in the first collection `$evaluatorGroup` there are 5 surveys I would want to add the value to each one, same thing with the `$evaluatorUser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I came up with

```
foreach ($evaluatorUser as $eU) {
    $eid = Evaluation::where('id', $eU->evaluation_id)->pluck('survey_id')->first();
    $answered = SurveyAnswer::where('survey_id', $eid)->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->count();
    if ($answered > 0){
        $eU['answered'] = true;
    }
}

foreach ($evaluatorGroup as $eG) {
    $eid = Evaluation::where('id', $eG->evaluation_id)->pluck('survey_id')->first();
    $answered = SurveyAnswer::where('survey_id', $eid)->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->count();
    if ($answered > 0){
        $eG['answered'] = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it. One way would be to manually iterate over records --- which is painful, a sample would be..

```
foreach($evaluatorGroup as $k1 => $Evaluator)
    foreach($Evaluator->evaluation->survey as $k2 => $Survey) // assuming EvaluationEvaluator <-> evaluation is one to one relationship
        $evaluatorGroup[$k1]->evaluation->survey[$k2]->answered = true;
```

The smart way is to go to your `Survey` model (which I believe is in App\Surveys or something like that) and append the `answered` property to it:

```
public $answered = null; // true, false, foo, bar whatever value you want
```

---

Sure you can leave the property there with whatever value you want to. If you want you can set it to true by default:

```
public $answered = true;
```

Though if you want to change the value of the property based on other factors (such as the value of other table columns from your model) you should use [Eloquent mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators). Suppose you want to automatically set the value of `answered` to true, once column `answer`. You can use the code below:

```
// inside model
public $answered = null;

public function getAnsweredAttribute($value) // $this->answered is passed here
{
    return empty($this->answer) ? false : true;
}

// outside model
$Survey->answered; // outputs false/true if $Survey->answer is empty/not
```

Hope this answer helps you.